# Assigning hostnames in umbraco

Tags: umbraco

I'm setting up af multi lingual page with the umbraco cms.

I have a content structure that looks like this:

- Content

  - da

    - danish subpage 1
    - danish subpage 2
  - en

    - english subpage 1
    - english subpage 2

I would like the routing to be something like:

http://mysite.dk should go to http://mysite.dk/da/danish subpage 1

http://mysite.dk/da/ should go to http://mysite.dk/da/danish subpage 1 (as well)

http://mysite.dk/en/ should go to http://mysite.dk/en/english subpage 1

I know I need to set up the hostnames in umbraco, but I can't figure out how to do that. I don't have access to IIS as it's in a hosted environment.

Comment: Did you ever get a fix for how to do this?

Answer (score 7):

you just right click on a node and select the 'hostnames' option which appears, then follow the instructions that appear

But I think you will also need to add the hostname to IIS.

Comment: on the da node add the hostname `mysite.dk/da/`  yes you can add a first level folder, I don't think you can add any other level of folder in the hostname field.