# Umbraco template site

Tags: umbraco

Is it possible to create a templated multi-site setup in Umbraco.  What I mean specifically, is there a way a user can create a new site in Umbraco, but that site has already been setup with templates and items that are prepopulated into the new site, when it is created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend looking into Continuous Integration. I've explored this kind of possibility in the past, and got quite far with it. The problem is that before I managed to finish, a new release came out and most of my code broke! :-)

Check out Anthony Dang's video about how he has produced single-click deployments of empty solutions. I love some of the stuff that this guy has been creating. Hopefully it is exactly what you are after too!

http://thecogworks.co.uk/blog/posts/2012/november/automation-sparta-standard-naming-across-the-project-universe/

There's also a video on YouTube in which he talks about how they do it.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WxE0qu4W0go

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is no. But check out my answer to [microsite in umbraco](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11226912/1110395) for some possible workarounds. I'm thinking you might have to create several replica document types for each "template" you want to use so that when the user creates a new "site", they can then choose which "template" they want to use.