# Umbraco Multiple Sites, Same Template but different CSS files

Tags: razor, xpath, content-management-system, umbraco

I have multiple sites residing inside one umbraco CMS for one client. The sites has many design items in common but the designer had to make one shared css file with a few different ones specific to each site.

Now, I ran into a problem with selecting the relevant css file for a site page. If a user is viewing page1 on site X then I must use css X, but if the user is viewing page1 on site Y I must use css Y.

Any idea how to do it? I thought about using Razor inside the template and check the domain name or the homepage doctype for that domain, any better ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check this answer to [microsite in umbraco](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11224906/microsite-in-umbraco/11226912#11226912). It gives a pretty good explanation on how to style different sites within the same Umbraco instance. It's mostly geared towards master pages, but it should apply razor views as well.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using razor to find what site you are on. You most probably have several "site" nodes at your root with managed hostnames (I'm guessing here). Create a macro to include your stylesheets and using naming conventions, include both specific and generic stylesheets.

```
<umbraco:Macro ID="Macro1" Alias="Stylesheets" runat="server" />
```

Then the macro:

```
var site = CurrentModel.AncestorOrSelf("Site");
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/generic.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/site/@site.Name.css" media="all" />
```

You can do the same thing with javascript files if you need.