# how to implement microsite in umbraco

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco8

I am new to umbraco and my client want microsites in umbraco 8 but i don't know how to implement microsite and I am confuse how to start any one please guide me how to implement microsite's in umbraco.
Thanks in advance

implementation of microsites in umbraco 8

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11224906/microsite-in-umbraco?rq=2 maybe?

Comment: i am not getting this solution thats why i putted new question.btw thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use Umbraco 8 anymore. Use Umbraco 10 which will be supported for a few years or Umbraco 11 is you like to live on the edge an new things.

If you don't know how to start with Umbraco, I would suggest to first dig into the [Getting Started](https://docs.umbraco.com/umbraco-cms/tutorials/creating-a-basic-website/getting-started) documentation from Umbraco. It gives you at least an idea how to work with Umbraco.

If you need more information, please be more specific on what you exactly need.